# PHP: Why is the answer to this addition 20 and not 22?

Tags: php

Why is the output to this 20, and not 22? Seeing as you're adding 10 + 0xA(which is 10 in HEX) + 2.

```
$a = 010;
$b = 0xA;
$c = 2;

print $a + $b + $c;

Output: 20.
```

Comment: octal+HEx+dec Check now!

Comment: None of the answers has linked to PHP's integer handling docs, so [here you are...](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's correct!

(Because the first number is `octal` so if you want it to be interpreted as a decimal you have to remove the first 0)
Se:

```
$a = 010;  //Octal -> 8
$b = 0xA;  //Hex   -> 10
$c = 2;    //Dec   -> 2

print $a + $b + $c;  //20
```

Output:

```
20
```

Comment: Oh how did I miss the Octal part. Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

See [the manual for numbers](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php):

> To use octal notation, precede the number with a 0 (zero). To use hexadecimal notation precede the number with 0x. To use binary notation precede the number with 0b.

`010` is an octal number (it starts with a `0` which isn't followed by a decimal point), which is `8` in decimal.

Answer (score 1):

This will solve:

```
<?php
$a = 10;
$b = 0xA;
$c = 2;

print $a + $b + $c;
?>
```

The 0 leading for $a was putting is as an Octal value, not decimal one.